# Post Sign-up Registration Form

Tags: oauth, openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c, auth0, okta

I'm looking to use an identity service such as `Azure B2C`, `Auth0` or `OKTA` to secure my application.

After the user signs up for an account, I need to display a custom registration form in my application in order to complete the registration. This form requires a business process behind the scenes and therefore it can't be part of the Identity Service (IDS are quite limited to capturing static data).

**How do I ensure the user has completed the registration form on my application, when they sign in?**

I'm thinking of using a claim such as `"RegistrationComplete"` and setting this to `False` when the user signs up. After they've signed up I can update this claim to be `True`.

I can't find any information online about this scenario so I not entirely sure its standard best practice.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I work at Okta

Okta does have some features which should allow this.  You can pull properties from the user's profile in Okta and put those properties on tokens as claims when the user is authenticating.  So the user profile holds the state you care about.  Your app/service can then read this claim from the token to determine if the form should be shown.  Once the form is complete, your backend service can use the Okta APIs to update this user profile state, and then send the user through the authorize flow again to get a new token with the updated claim (specifying to not prompt for re-authentication when going through the authorize flow again).

Comment: Brilliant. I'm guessing from your answer that this is quite a common thing to do. I just wasn't too sure whether there were other options to achieve this. Thank you. Btw Okta looks awesome!

Comment: We were trialling Azure B2C using this scenario. After updating the claims we perform a silent refresh however, the updated claims are present as B2C caches this (Takes about 30 seconds). Does OKTA do something similar?

Answer (score 0):

There is a restful provider feature in azure ad b2c. Using the Rest Apis from any service along with custom policies in b2c, we can get user input and save that user input to any database. The REST apis can be used to orchestrate any step.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-rest-api-step-custom